# Include attributes from another referenced model in a filtered get request on django REST framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-filter

My goal is to include the `name` attribute of the `Brand` model a `Product` references through `models.ForeignKey`, when I make a get request for products. Exactly what this piece of code returns in the python shell:

```py
Product.objects.all().values('name', 'brand__name',)
```

returns this:

```
[
    {'name': 'B-1', 'brand__name': 'B-brand'}, 
    {'name': 'B-2', 'brand__name': 'B-brand'}, 
    {'name': 'C-1', 'brand__name': 'C-brand'}
]
```

Im already using `django-filters` to filter my get requests.

Models:

```py
class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Serializers:

```py
class BrandSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Brand
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'name')


class ProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'name', 'brand')
```

Filter:

```py
class ProductFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    name = filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr = 'icontains')
    brand__name = filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr = 'icontains')

    class Meta: 
        model = Product
        fields = ('name' 'brand__name',)
```

View:

```py
class ProductView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    filterset_class = ProductFilter
```

with `brand__name` in the filterSet, i am able to reference the name of the brand model a certain product is referencing and retrieve it. My goal is to also include that same name of the Brand along with the attributes of a product when I make the `get request`, which currently only yields the url/reference of the brand (along with all other atributes of `Product`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return as a flat dictionary, you can do like this.

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    brand_name = serializer.CharField(source="brand__name")
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'sku', 'name', 'brand_name', 'price')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive solved my own issue, by defining `brand` as `brandSerializer` in `ProductSerializer`, i was able to return the whole brand object along with the product info, just like this:

```py
class ProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    brand = BrandSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'sku', 'name', 'brand', 'price')
```